# Understanding hibernate Session Initialization

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I'm using `Spring 4.2.1` and `Hiberante 5` and now trying to understand how spring initializes the Session declared in the Spring Beans Definition as follows:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <!-- properties -->
</bean>
```

I found that so called [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.orm/3.1.0/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.java#LocalSessionFactoryBean) implements `FactoryBean<SessionFactory>`. [Taking this into account](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) it's clear why we define the `SessionFactory` definition to be injected with the class `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean` but end up with the instance of `SessionFactory`. Now, what I was confused by is the method [getCurrentSession](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.0.CR1/org/hibernate/internal/SessionFactoryImpl.java#SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession%28%29):

```
public Session  getCurrentSession() throws HibernateException {
    if ( currentSessionContext == null ) {
        throw new HibernateException( "No CurrentSessionContext configured!" );
    }
    return currentSessionContext.currentSession();
}
```

which delegates the actual session creation to the [SpringSessionContext](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.orm/3.1.1/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/SpringSessionContext.java#SpringSessionContext.currentSession%28%29) and in my case it's being retrieved by this [piece of code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.orm/3.1.1/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/SpringSessionContext.java#SpringSessionContext.currentSession%28%29):

```
SessionHolder sessionHolder = (SessionHolder) value;
Session session = sessionHolder.getSession();
```

But the `session` is actually an instance of `org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl` the direct base class `org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl` of which itself has the property [protected transient SessionFactoryImpl factory](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.hibernate/com.springsource.org.hibernate/3.3.1/org/hibernate/impl/AbstractSessionImpl.java#AbstractSessionImpl.0factory).

So, the `SessionFactory` has the `CurrentSessionContext` property which in my case holds `SessionHolder` which in turn holds the actual `Session` instance. But the `SessionImpl` again has a property of the type `SessionFactory`.

I cannot understand the circular. Couldn't you explain it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Spring implementation of `CurrentSessionContext` does not hold `SessionHolder`, instead `Sessionholder` is retrieved every time that `currentSession` method is invoked. See this:

```
Object value = TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(this.sessionFactory);
...
SessionHolder sessionHolder = (SessionHolder) value;
```

So, in your case there are injected some implementations, but it can be another one in case of different configuration.

I think the main purpose of that design is to have a good separation of concerns. The main purpose of the `SessionContext` is to relate transaction manager and session holder to provide you a well configured session depending on transaction configuration.

There are other implementations of `CurrentSessionContext`, I believe hibernate has at least three implementations, so the scenario that you have described depends on the spring configuration that injects such classes.

As javaDoc states:

> CurrentSessionContext implementation can also be specified in custom SessionFactory setup through the "hibernate.current_session_context_class"

Comment: Yes, indeed, you're absolutely right. I figured out that `TransactionSynchronizationManager` has a `private static ThreaLocal` field called `resources`. And the actual binding the `SessionHolder` is being performed by wrapping the Session intance into the holder as `new SessionHolder(session)` and then binding with the key `sessionFactory`.  But it's still a little hard to understand how the circularityness provides the separation of concerns....